# Python/sqlite3: improving performance when executing thousands of "SELECT" queries

Tags: sql, python-2.7, optimization, sqlite

Here is  simple use-case:

```
selectString = "SELECT MAX(shear_strain) FROM detailed_structure_info WHERE elementGroup = ? AND element = ? AND analysis = ?"
selectInputTuple = list(itertools.product(elementGroups, elementNumbers, analysisNumbers))

results = []
numExecutes = 0

for selectInputTuple in selectInputTuples:
    c = ei_cursor.execute(selectString, selectInputTuple)
    results.append(c.fetchone()[0])
    numExecutes += 1

    print "{} out of {} commands completed...".format(numExecutes, len(selectInputTuples))
```

Right now, it takes about 1 second to go through the loop each time, and one may need to loop through hundreds of times. I have thought about how I could execute as large a SELECT statement as possible, but for the moment, I think this is the smallest I can go, since I absolutely need to aggregate one particular column before moving on. So, how else could I write my SELECT statement to optimize for speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping through tuples to for an aggregation seems wasteful.  Just use `group by` and get all the results at once:

```
SELECT elementGroup, element, analysis, MAX(shear_strain) as max_shear_strain
FROM detailed_structure_info 
GROUP BY elementGroup, element, analysis;
```

If you have to run a separate query, for some reason, then create an index:

```
create index idx_detailed_structure_info_4
    on detailed_structure_info(elementGroup, element, analysis, shear_strain);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am not sure I understand the second bit though..."If you have to run a separate query, for some reason, then create an index...". Could you explain that?

Comment: The index will speed up the queries that you are running now in the loop.  The first method does a single query to eliminate the need for the loop.

Comment: P.S. Your first suggestion worked like a charm....from 300 seconds down to 10 seconds! Wow.

Comment: Ah, you mean, if I have to run a separate query that needs stuff from the same column later on? That way, I have already "pre-organized" the data in some sense?

Comment: @user89 . . . Yes, I think that is one way to understand what I mean.  An index can be thought of as "pre-organizing" the data for a particular purpose.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Would it have sufficed to create the index on `elementGroup, element, analysis` without `shear_strain`?

Comment: @unutbu . . . Such an index would be a big, big help.  But the query would still have to access the data pages to get the value of `shear_strain`.  The index in the answer is a "covering index" for the query, meaning the original data pages don't need to be accessed.